# CDK register region fact using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to register a region_info Fact using Python, and I'm struggling to understand the [Python CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.region_info/README.html#supplying-new-or-missing-information)

Attempted the following

```py
import jsii
from aws_cdk import region_info

region_name = "rando-region-east-1"

elbv2_account = region_info.Fact.find(region_name, region_info.FactName.ELBV2_ACCOUNT)
print(elbv2_account)  # None

@jsii.implements(region_info.IFact)
class MyElbv2Fact:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.region = region_name,
        self.name = region_info.FactName.ELBV2_ACCOUNT,
        self.value = "111111111111"
        
region_info.Fact.register(
    fact=MyElbv2Fact(),
    allow_replacing=True
)
elbv2_account = region_info.Fact.find(region_name, region_info.FactName.ELBV2_ACCOUNT)
print(elbv2_account)  # Still None
```

The region fact never gets registered

I feel like I'm missing something simple

Comment: is this part of a stack? If so, dose your stack at your app level have env defined? If you don't, then region/environment specific thing will not be available for constructs to use

Comment: Yes part of a stack, and the [env](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html) variable with `account` and `region` are passed in that property

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out with properties and setters

```py
import jsii
from aws_cdk import region_info

@jsii.implements(region_info.IFact)
class ElbAlt:
    def __init__(self, region, value, name):
        self._name = name
        self._region = region
        self._value = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        self._name = val

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        self._value = val

    @property
    def region(self):
        return self._region

    @region.setter
    def region(self, val):
        self._region = val


region_info.Fact.register(
    ElbAlt(
        region="rando-region-east-1",
        value="111111111111",
        name=region_info.FactName.ELBV2_ACCOUNT
    ),
    True,
)
```

Comment: You don't actually need setters, it works fine without them. Also, your original code assigned tuples to the first two properties instead of strings (due to the trailing commas).